# Python unittesting request.get with mocking, not raising specific exception

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a simple function that sends a get request to an API, and I want to be able to write a Unit test to assert that the scriprt prints an error and then exits if the request returns an exception.

```
def fetch_members(self):
    try:
        r = requests.get(api_url, auth=('user', api_key))
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as error:
        print(error)
        sys.exit(1)
```

I've tried the following test but the HTTPError is never raised

```
import requests
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('sys.exit')
@patch('sys.stdout', new_callable=StringIO)
@patch('requests.get')
def test_fetch_members_with_bad_request(self, mock_get, mock_stdout,
                                        mock_exit):
    response = requests.Response()
    response.status_code = 400  # Bad reqeust
    mock_get.return_value = response
    mock_get.side_effect = requests.exceptions.HTTPError
    with self.assertRaises(requests.exceptions.HTTPError):
        fetch_members()
        mock_exit.assert_called_once_with(1)
        self.assertIsNotNone(mock_stdout.getvalue())
```

How would I go about correctly patching requests.get to always raise some sort of error?

Comment: Your sample code *does* cause the exception to be raised, but your function *catches and handles it*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function catches and handles the exception:

```
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as error:
```

This means it'll *never* propagate further, so your `assertRaises()` fails. Just assert that `sys.exit()` has been called, that's enough.

There is also no point in setting a return value; the call raises an exception instead. The following should suffice:

```
@patch('sys.exit')
@patch('sys.stdout', new_callable=StringIO)
@patch('requests.get')
def test_fetch_members_with_bad_request(self, mock_get, mock_stdout,
                                        mock_exit):
    mock_get.side_effect = requests.exceptions.HTTPError
    fetch_members()
    mock_exit.assert_called_once_with(1)
    self.assertIsNotNone(mock_stdout.getvalue())
```